# Implementing jQuery .next() in a simple image slide show

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qBQD4/

It's pretty simple really; I want the right arrow to move the images forwards, left arrow to move them backwards in a simple slideshow. I have multiple slideshows running on the page that this code will be implemented on, hence why I've gone the .next() route instead of just specifying a unique div id. The HTML is:

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="slideButtons">
        <span class="prev"><</span>
        <span class="next">/ ></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="gallery" id="olympGallery">
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8aA7W.jpg" alt="" title="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/jE7vj.jpg" alt="" title="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/L7lVg.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the jQuery code is:

```
var speed = 100;

$(".prev").click(function() {
    var now = $(this).next("ul.gallery").children(":visible"),
        last = $(this).next("ul.gallery").children(":last"),
        prev = now.prev();
        prev = prev.index() == -1 ? last : prev;
    now.fadeOut(speed, function() {prev.fadeIn(speed);});
});

$(".next").click(function() {
    var now = $(this).next("ul.gallery").children(':visible'),
        first = $(this).next("ul.gallery").children(':first'),
        next = now.next();
        next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
    now.fadeOut(speed, function() {next.fadeIn(speed);});
});

$(".gallery li").click(function() {
    var first = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
        next = $(this).next();
        next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
    $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {next.fadeIn(speed);});
});
```

And finally, a bit of CSS:

```
.prev, .next {position: relative; padding: 3px; font-size:50px; font-weight: 900; cursor:pointer;
}

.gallery li{display:none; list-style:none;}
.gallery li:first-child {display:block;}

.gallery img {
    max-height:550px
}
```

The 3rd function works fine (clicking the image progresses to the next in the series). However, the first two are completely broken. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the prev and next functions you've forgotten to ascend to the clicked div's parent before trying to find its associated gallery, i.e.:

```
var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":visible")
```

Working sample at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/qBQD4/1/

FWIW, you should also really separate out that step into a separate variable, and then find the relevant images:

```
var gallery = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery");
var first = gallery.children(':first');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use .next(*selector*), you are looking for the next siblings matching the selector.
In other word, you are looking for the next elements at the same level in the DOM tree.

Here is the corrected jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QALEE/

All you need is to use $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery") to be at the good level to select the next "ul.gallery" element .

Answer (score 0):

Wrote it in 20 minutes..may be have some unofficial codelines, but works fine.
JS

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var currentBox=0;

        $("#Right").click(function () {

            var tobox = $(".mainbox").length;
            if(currentBox<tobox-1){
            if (currentBox == 0)
            {
                //if the first slide 
                $(".mainbox:nth(0)").hide();
                $(".mainbox:nth(1)").show();
                currentBox = currentBox + 1;
                //alert("to right:" + tobox +currentBox) ;
            }
            else {

                currentBox = currentBox + 1;
                var h = currentBox - 1;
                var s = currentBox;
                $(".mainbox:nth(" + h + ")").hide();
                $(".mainbox:nth(" + s + ")").show();

                //alert("to right:" + tobox + currentBox);

            }
            } else {
                $(".mainbox:nth(0)").show();
                var a = tobox - 1;
                $(".mainbox:nth(" + a + ")").hide();
                currentBox = 0;
                //alert("end");
            }


        });

        $("#Left").click(function () {



                var tobox = $(".mainbox").length;
                if (currentBox == 0)
                {//if the last slide

                    var a = tobox - 1;
                    $(".mainbox:nth(" + a + ")").show();
                    $(".mainbox:nth(0)").hide();
                    currentBox = a;
                   // alert("to left:" + tobox +currentBox) ;
                }
                else
                {
                   // alert("Current box:"+ currentBox);
                   // 
                    var h = currentBox;
                    var s = currentBox-1;
                    $(".mainbox:nth(" +h+ ")").hide();
                    $(".mainbox:nth(" + s + ")").show();

                   // alert("to right:" + tobox + currentBox);
                    currentBox = currentBox - 1;

                }
            //else { alert("end"); }


            });
        });


</script>
```

HTML

```
    <div class="sliderOutbx">

    <div class="Content">
        <div class="NavLeft"><span id="Left">Left</span></div>

        <div class="mainbox">
            <div class="box">1</div>
            <div class="box">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainbox" style="display:none;">
            <div class="box">3</div>
            <div class="box">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainbox" style="display:none;">
            <div class="box">5</div>
            <div class="box">6</div>
        </div>

        <div class="NavRight"><span id="Right">Right</span></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Hope this might help to someone save a day.